# In Javascript/Typescript, how to check a http web site is accessible from https web site?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here's what I'm trying to do.

1. I have a web site hosted on https.
2. This web site shows a link to another http web site "only" if this http web site can be reached. Based on where my web site is hosted, it may or may not have the access to this http web site - that's why I need to check whether it's reachable or not first.
3. If this link is visible, user can click this link and it will open up the http web site in a new tab using `window.open("http://xxx")`.

In doing #2 using fetch API with HEAD method, I get the following error 
`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxx' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://yyy'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.` Is there any other way to implement #2 without causing this error?

Comment: Are you running on the same domain? Are you in control of the other site? You will still likely run into cross origin issues if there is not an allow header for your domain.

Comment: It's running on the same domain if it's reachable. I don't have any control of the other http-based site. I'm not sure about what you meant by `not an allow header for your domain`.